# save file to buffer?

Tags: php, swiftmailer

I have a PDF stored in `$fileGenerated` - the PDF is generated on the fly by wkhtmltopdf and it's in memory, in that variable.

I need to send this in an email with Swiftmailer.

I have tried creating a `newInstance` of a `Swift_Attachment`, and attaching `$fileGenerated` - and it works. But it always gets caught in the spam filter.

If I attach a file using `Swift_Attachment::fromPath()` then the spam filter doesn't catch it.

So I want to save `$fileGenerated` to some location, then reference it in `fromPath()` and then delete the file.

If I pick a location on disk and use file_put_contents, I have some trouble deleting it (permission denied). Instead of dealing with permissions, I was wondering if it's possible to save this pdf to some sort of temporary memory buffer like php://buffer/myfile.pdf ?

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: You should rather figure out what the difference is in the email that is eventually generated via both methods, and try to patch it up so the same email is generated regardless how you attach the file. A spam filter can't tell how you've used `Swift_Attachment`...!

Comment: I believe it might be the message id. It comes out as something like 
`~B54912e8c0000.54911e9a0000.0001.mml.52463062@mysite.net` even though I explicitly change it with `setId()` to `md5($name . microtime(true)) . '@mysite.net` - either Swiftmailer or the mailserver is changing that message ID and I don't know why. So that is why I am looking at this alternative instead.

Comment: For what it's worth, if I call `getId()` on the swift mailer object the moment before it is sent I see the proper md5 ID. So I'm not sure what causes it to change.